# Time stamp difference Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written down a query which is given below to fetch the record from some table.

```
select g.logtekst DESCRIPTION,g.loggruppe loggroup,TO_CHAR(d.logdato, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') logdate 
,d.logtype,d.systemnavn,d.rkibrugernr username,d.psp_id customernumber  
from logbasis_Trans d,logtyper g where d.logtype=g.logtype and d.logdato>Sysdate-720 .

VIR opslag  VIR 03-10-2015 09:53:38 250 NTMF    CONDLOGB    93939393
VIR opslag  VIR 03-10-2015 13:53:52 250 NTMF    CONDLOGB    93939393
Sog opslag  VER 03-10-2015 14:45:30 251 NTMF    CONDOLDB    91919191
Sog opslag  VER 03-10-2015 14:45:31 251 NTMF    CONDOLDB    91919191
Sag opslag  VIR 03-10-2015 14:45:30 251 NTMF    JONDOLDB    95919191
Sog opslag  VJR 03-10-2015 14:45:31 251 NTMF    CFNDOLDB    91719191
```

This basically list out rows as result from the query.

Now from this I want only such **customerNumber** (Last Column in this case) which have all the remaining columns same(Log Group Same) but the time difference is <1 Minute between these columns.

In this case the first and second row are multiple entries as time stamp differs by 1 minute and 3-4 columns but not 5 and 6 columns.

Can these query modified to get such data or some manipulation can take place in the excel only remove these type of duplicate records.

Comment: have you ever looked at analytical functions?

Comment: I know analytical function.But it requires some more complex code other than analytical function.

Comment: have a look at the `LAG` function http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

use this statement to get the minute differences:

`(d.logdato - LAG(d.logdato, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY d.psp_id, d.logtype ORDER BY d.logdato))*24*60 AS diff_min`

explanation:
we get logdato from this row and subtract logdato from the preceding row (`LAG 1`) within a group of records (`OVER`) with same psp_id and logtype (`PARTITION BY`) ordered by logdato (`ORDER BY`), finally we multiply the result to get the minutes from days

Comment: thankyou so much,Following query will give me only unique customer numbers from these               " select distinct customernumber from ( select g.logtekst DESCRIPTION,g.loggruppe loggroup,TO_CHAR(d.logdato, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') logdate 
,d.logtype,d.systemnavn,d.psp_id customernumber,(d.logdato - LAG(d.logdato, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY d.psp_id, d.logtype ORDER BY d.logdato))*24*60 AS diff_min 
from logbasis_Trans d,logtyper g where d.logtype=g.logtype and d.logdato>Sysdate-720  
group by d.logtype,g.logtekst,g.loggruppe,d.logdato,d.systemnavn,d.psp_id) where diff_min<=1"